# Update AVL tree code to perform find OR insert

Tags: c++, c, r, segmentation-fault, avl-tree

I would like to use AVL trees in a particular algorithm. I'm making an R package so I want to stick to C or C++ implementations (currently using a C implementation).

I got base code for an AVL tree implementation from: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-2-deletion/

I am trying to make a new function that will insert a new node if the key is not in the tree, otherwise if it is in the tree, give me access to the node so I can look at it. I'm a noobie C programmer though so I am running into several snags.

Here is my current implementation. In the main function I insert a few keys and print a pre-order to check that insertions work correctly (they do). Then I try to insert a key that is already in the tree. This leads to a seg-fault :( can anyone help me out? This is probably just a simple problem with my C:

```
struct node* specialInsert(struct node* root, struct node* result, int *numBefore, int key, bool *flag){
    //We are inserting a new (non-root) node!
    if (root == NULL){
        struct node* res = newNode(key);
        res->equalCount = key;
        *numBefore = 0;
        *flag = true;
        return(res);
    }else if( key == root->key){
        *flag = false;
        *numBefore = root->leftCount;
        root->equalCount = root->equalCount + key;

        if(result == NULL){
            struct node* result = newNode(root->key);
        }

        //printf("result key is: %d\n", result->key);

        return root;
    }else if( key < root->key){
        root->left = specialInsert(root->left, result, numBefore, key, flag);
        root->leftCount = root->leftCount + key;
        //if(*flag) update(root, key);
        //else return(root->left);
        update(root,key);
    } else if( key > root->key){
        root->right = specialInsert(root->right, result, numBefore, key, flag);
        *numBefore = *numBefore + root->leftCount + root->equalCount;
        root->rightCount = root->rightCount + key;
        //if(*flag) update(root, key);
        //else return(root->right);
        update(root,key);
    }
}
struct node* findOrInsert(struct node* root, struct node* result, int *numBefore, int key){
    bool *flag;
    bool val = false;
    flag = &val;

    /* 1.  Perform the normal BST rotation */
    if (root == NULL){
        struct node* res = newNode(key);
        *numBefore = 0;
        res->equalCount = key;
        return(res);
    }
    else return( specialInsert(root, result, numBefore, key, flag) );


}
```

and in a main function I have:

```
struct node *root2 = NULL;
struct node *result = NULL;

root2 = findOrInsert(root2, result, x, 9);
root2 = findOrInsert(root2, result, x, 5);
root2 = findOrInsert(root2, result, x, 10);
root2 = findOrInsert(root2, result, x, 0);
root2 = findOrInsert(root2, result, x, 6);
root2 = findOrInsert(root2, result, x, 11);
root2 = findOrInsert(root2, result, x, -1);
root2 = findOrInsert(root2, result, x, 1);
root2 = findOrInsert(root2, result, x, 2);


preOrder(root2);
printf("\n");

root2 = findOrInsert(root2, result, x, 9);
printf("Number of elements less than %d: %d\n", result->key,result->leftCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply rely on code that others have written.

One such implementation is the [Boost implementation of AVL Trees](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/intrusive/avltree.html) which you could access easily via the [CRAN package BH](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=BH) which gives you Boost Headers for use in R (and C++).

Of course, you may also relish debugging your own data structure, and there is merit in that too. In that case `gdb` may prove helpful...

Comment: I wish I had my own personal Dirk on my shoulder to help guide me through life

Comment: I would want that too ;-)